# release all modules into one parent name of the project in Gitlab CICD pipeline

Tags: maven, gitlab, pipeline, cicd

My project is Maven based and has various sub-modules.

```
Main_prj_name

  submodule1
   src
   pom.xml
  submodule2
   src
   pom.xml

.gitlab-ci.yml
pom.xml
```

I'm using gitlab pipeline to build and release it to Nexus repo manager. Everything works well, except that when the rpm is released on Nexus, it is being released separately for each and every module.
What I want is, it should be consolidated into one parent name (Main_prj_name), which should contains the submodules inside.

main pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.abc.zyx</groupId>
<name>Main_prj_name</name>
<artifactId>Main_prj_name_2.11</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modules>
    <module>submodule1</module>
    <module>submodule2</module>
<modules>
```

submodule pom.xml

```
<artifactId>submodule1_2.11</artifactId>
  
<parent>
   <artifactId>My_proj_name_2.11</artifactId>
   <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
   <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant information areas... as you wrote you release an rpm ? How and where is the RPM being made / configured ? How is Maven called etc.. ? That's all missiung?

Comment: thanks for replying @khmarbaise , so my pipeline has 2 stages, 1st is the build  - which builds the project ( `mvn clean install` ) and second is the release ( `mvn release:prepare` followed by `mvn release:perform `) which generates the rpm.

Comment: First I doubt that you only generate the rpm during the release phase if so that your build sounds a bind wrong...apart from that I need more details: How is the configuration done? Is the rpm build via Maven or via external tool? if so the how? etc..Also why using `mvn clean install` wouldn't `mvn clean verify` not sufficient?